# Incrementing a counter to an endpoint over a specific amount of time

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, counter, increment, duration

I am incrementing a counter, starting at 0, up to a specified endpoint and over a specific duration.

A function is called, over the duration, *an indefinite amount of times* to perform the incrementing of the counter.

The goal is to increment the counter up to the endpoint at the exact end of the duration.

What is not known is by what number to increment the counter, based on the endpoint and the duration.

**My question is how can I determine the number to increment the counter by using only the endpoint and duration as known variables?**

Here is a code example to illustrate:

```
let duration = 2000; // two seconds
let endpoint = 1239; 
let counter = 0;
let numberToIncrementBy = ''; // this is the unknown

function myFunc() {
    if (counter >= endpoint) {
        // reached the endpoint
        return counter;
    }

    counter += numberToIncrementBy;
    return counter;
}
```

**UPDATE: I've added more details behind the reason for this question below:**

I'm using [progressbarjs](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to create an animated progress bar. To use it, you create a new Shape object using `ProgressBar.ShapeName()` and pass it a container element as it's first arguments. You can also pass it an options object where you can define a duration property.

```
duration = 2000; // duration variable from above
let circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('#the-container', { duration: duration });
```

Once the Shape object has been created, you can call the animate method on it, and pass in a `progress` variable - a number from 0 to 1 - to indicate where the animation should stop.

```
circle.animate(0.8); // 80% of progress bar
```

What I've done to "solve" my problem - and this is still a work in progress - is to create a function that invokes ProgressBars `animate` function while also calling a custom function that increments a counter within the duration of the animation up to a certain endpoint.

```
let invokeAnimation = function() {
    let progress = 1400; // arbitary number
    let endpoint = 2100; // also arbitrary but must be larger than progress variable

    // manufacture a progress variable to pass to circle.animate() to determine - between 0 and 1 - where the animation should stop
    let progressEnd = (progress / endpoint).toFixed(2); // 0.67 

    /* set up a function using setInterval to rapidly call a function */
    let counter = 0;

    // NOTE: this variable is critical in ensuring that the counter reaches the progress amount in the time it takes for the animation to complete
    let incrementValue = Math.round(progress / duration * 100); // multiply by 100 and use math round to get a whole number

    let outputStr = " of " + endpoint; // will be combined with progress/counter and output as a string alongside the progress bar in the UI
    let intId = setInterval(frame, 50); // declare a handle to the setInterval function to be able to later CLEAR the interval when no longer needed

    function frame() {
        // the counter has reached its target
        if (counter >= progress) {
            // clear setInterval
            clearInterval(intId);

            // Output text
            // NOTE: circle.setText() is a defined by the ProgressBarJS API and sets the output text of the Shape object
            circle.setText(progress + outputStr );
            return;
        } else {
            circle.setText(counter + outputStr);
            counter += incrementValue;
        }
    }
```

The effect of this code is that `progress` and `endpoint` values can be defined and within a set `duration`, a counter will be incremented up to the value of `progress`. This creates a dynamic textual output that is in sync with a graphical progress meter or bar.

Thanks to @cybersam and @NolanWalker for attempting to answer my misinformed question from above. It was, in fact, @NolanWalker's suggestion of using setTimeout, plus the discovery of this example on the W3School's site of using [setInterval to create a dynamic progress bar](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval_progressbar) that inspired my result.

Please note, too, that the above code does not factor in the function call, explained in my original post, that is called an indefinite amount of times. This function is a result of the `circle.animate()` method's [`step` function](http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/parameters/#step-parameter), that is used to create the animation.

And finally, the `setInterval` function takes as it's second argument a frame rate. In my code above, I've set it to `50` rather arbitrarily. My code does not factor `frame rate` into its conclusion and I think this is an area that can be improved upon (but I'm happy enough with the result of my code - and lazy enough - that I will leave it as if for now!).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using the setTimeout function or use an Observable for this.

```
Observable.interval(5000)
    .takeWhile(() => !condition)
    .subscribe(i => { 
        // will check every 5 seconds until condition is met
        // executable code
        // set condition to exit 
    })

setTimeout(() => {
  // executable code
  // stops in 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, since you can call the incrementation function **any number of times**, it is not possible to satisfy your requirements unless the increment is not a fixed number. As an example: the "increment" could always be 0 -- *except* when you reach the `duration`, at which point it would just be `endpoint`. (In essence, the "increment" would not actually increment the counter until the very end.)

This `getInc0Func` function *returns* an incrementation function that always returns 0 until the `duration` is reached:

```
function getInc0Func(duration, endpoint) {

  let end = Date.now() + duration;

  return function() {
    if (Date.now() >= end) {
      return endpoint;
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
```

However, practically speaking, the number of times you would probably be calling the incrementation function is going to be "reasonable" (e.g., something less than 10 ^ 16 times). In that case you can use [Number.EPSILON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) instead of 0, so that every counter value will be different:

```
function getIncFunc(duration, endpoint) {

  let end = Date.now() + duration;
  let counter = 0;

  return function() {
    if (Date.now() >= end) {
      return endpoint;
    }
    return (counter += Number.EPSILON);
  }
}
```